# В выдаче Google категории сайта доступны по неправильным url

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search

У сайта в поисковой выдаче гугла появились категории по не ЧПУ ссылкам. Например, вместо `https://life-thai.com/category/countries/malaysia/`. Google показывает `https://life-thai.com/?cat=31`. Откуда Google всё это взял - не понятно. Везде используется ЧПУ. Sitemap.xml проверила, там тоже нигде таких ссылок нет.

Интересно, что при клике на `https://life-thai.com/?cat=31` в выдаче, открывается страница с url `https://life-thai.com/category/countries/malaysia/`. Т.е. происходит редирект. Но в .httaccess такой редирект не настроен.

Сайт работает на Wordpress. В Консоли вебмастера Google появилась ошибка "Дублирующиеся Title", что понятно.

**Вопрос:** как решить проблему, не закрывая от индексации категории?

Comment: Телепаты все разъехались, а специалисты работают с конкретными данными. Им нужен адрес сайта.

Comment: [вот она](https://life-thai.com)

Comment: Адрес в вопрос нужно добавить. Причём реальные. https://life-thai.com/?cat=987 не существует.

Comment: @SeVlad уточнила, добавила реальные url

Comment: В выдаче гугла действительно [мелькают](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YNa9ElkXn3gJ:https://life-thai.com/%3Fcat%3D951%20&cd=34&hl=ru&ct=clnk) не [канонические урлы](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru) (что говорит о том. что гугл может и не следовать им). А с технической точки зрения сделано всё правильно - и редирект есть, и в [сайтмапе](https://life-thai.com/category-sitemap.xml) всё правильно и каноникал прописан: <link rel="canonical" href="https://life-thai.com/category/countries/malaysia/"/> Т.е. на сайте делать ничего не нужно.

Comment: Почему в выдаче такое - вот тут не понятно. Не должно быть. Разве что раньше на сайте не было ЧПУ и это остатки.
Я думаю, что со временем должно пройти, гугл должен переиндексировать по каноническим урлам.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. ЧПУ используется с самого появления сайта. Но категории были закрыты от индексации до недавнего времени.